# Fortify scanning in Eclipse over maven projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, fortify

I have the Eclipse plugin for Fortify.
But it only runs on the Java projects.

We have some Java projects but they are Maven based non-Java projects. I can edit the `.project` file of the projects and change their type to Java to enable Fortify scanning.
But is there a better way to run Fortify scans on Maven based projects?

**EDIT** Had to do following steps as mentioned in some of the posts below

- Install the Maven Fortify plugin
- Added Maven fortify Plugin details in my application pom
- Ran translate and scan commands. It generated fpr files under the projects
- Follow this helpful blog too http://fortify-maven.blogspot.in/

The only Question which I still have is:

I have multiple projects where an fpr file for each project is created. Can I have a consolidated fpr file being created for all the projects in one place?

Cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortify has a plugin for Maven that you should be able to use. Check in this directory:

```
<Fortify Installation Folder>\Samples\advanced\maven-plugin
```

You compile the plugin into maven and then you can run the translate and scan commands from within Maven. That directory has sample code and the documentation is compiled when you build the plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot all for your helpful comments...i have one problem that these projects have come to me for scanning...so i just import them into eclipse as existing maven projects. I don't have any localy m2 repository setup in my local machine

Comment: I'm a novice Maven user, but I would assume that when you're using Eclipse with Maven it is building the repo based off the POM. It has to have the JARs to do the compile, so they're coming from somewhere. If you're only responsible for performing the scan, I would either use the Maven plugin to scan while building or use Audit Work Bench. With Audit Work Bench you can point to the source directory and just do the scan. You may have to hunt down some JAR files to get a complete scan.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your reply...does the code have to compile in Order to perform scanning ?

Comment: Not for Java. You can just point SCA to the source code while passing the class path and SCA will scan it.

Comment: Utilizing the maven plugin will indeed require that maven build the project.  Your local .m2 will be created when maven resolves the dependencies in the pom.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the package locally or integrate it as part of your build process. During the translation phase, the SCA Maven Plugin will search your jar file from the local repository and try to resolve classes in your application.


Follow the below commands,

1. mvn sca:clean
2. mvn sca:translate
3. mvn sca:scan

Answer (score 0):

When we ran the Static Code Analyzer (SCA) version 6.21.0005 in a maven build, the scan ran but failed to upload to the Fortify Software Security Center (SSC). The previous successful upload to the SSC was from the desktop Audit Work Bench with a Scan Engine version of 6.21.0007. We surmise this difference in minor versions caused the failure of the FPR file uploads to the Production SSC. When we revised the build script to load the FPR file into a new project, the upload worked, implying that there appears to be a bug on HP's side, which they have confirmed. We were able to do a workaround by creating a new project that only has FPR's generated from a single source. I recommend you use a single source for your SCA or at least use the same SCA version number if you must employ multiple scan sources.