# Fortify integration with Maven - install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, fortify

I want to run a Fortify scan against a Maven Eclipse project.

Where should I start?

I understand that I need to update my `pom.xml` file to include the Fortify plugin however do I also require to have Fortify SCA installed on my machine? (I'm running MacOS X). I have been trying to find a place to download Fortify SCA but have not been able find it.

I would appreciate it if someone could share some links to point me in the right direction in getting the setup complete.

Comment: The only place you can download Fortify is the HP Portal (https://softwaresupport.hp.com). Here's another post on how to use the maven plugin from Fortify: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742146/fortify-scanning-in-eclipse-over-maven-projects/29756342#29756342

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the Fortify installation is required, but it's pretty hard to get the maven sca plugin without it.  If you install on another machine you could copy just the plugin over, but then you wouldn't have the Audit Workbench application to work with the generated FPR.  As @Eric said, you have to get it through HP and it will not work without a license.

Once you get that installed you add profiles to your pom.xml to execute the sca targets:

```
<profile>
  <id>sca-clean</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.30</version>
        <configuration>
          <jre64>true</jre64>
          <buildId>myproject</buildId>
          <toplevelArtifactId>myproject.parent</toplevelArtifactId>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>


<profile>
  <id>sca-translate</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.30</version>
        <configuration>
          <jre64>true</jre64>
          <jreStack>8M</jreStack>
          <maxHeap>12000M</maxHeap>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <buildId>myproject</buildId>
          <toplevelArtifactId>myproject.parent</toplevelArtifactId>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
          <failOnSCAError>true</failOnSCAError>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>translate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>


<profile>
  <id>sca-scan</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.30</version>
        <configuration>
          <jre64>true</jre64>
          <jreStack>8M</jreStack>
          <maxHeap>12000M</maxHeap>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <buildId>myproject</buildId>
          <toplevelArtifactId>myproject.parent</toplevelArtifactId>
          <failOnSCAError>true</failOnSCAError>
          <upload>false</upload>
          <projectName>My Project Main Development</projectName>
          <projectVersion>${project.version}</projectVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Run the scan from the command line:

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfortify.sca.buildId=myproject -Dfortify.sca.toplevel.artifactId=myproject.parent com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:sca-maven-plugin:clean
```

Obviously, you will have to figure out the buildId and artifactId naming, and it varies a little depending on if you're using parent, aggregator, or nothing.

Comment: No *fpr* was generated in my case. I have to run `clean`, `translate` and `scan` as separate maven commands.

Comment: I found out that adding those 3 profiles to the pom.xml is not necessary.  After installing the Fortify maven plugin, I just had to run the 3 commands mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29808348/782011).

Answer (score 6):

Actually profiles are not needed, only the plugin configuration.

```
<build>
    <plugins> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.30</version>
            <configuration>
                <findbugs>true</findbugs>
                <htmlReport>true</htmlReport>
                <maxHeap>800M</maxHeap>
                <source>myJavaVersion</source>
                <buildId>myBuildId</buildId>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                <toplevelArtifactId>myTopLevelId</toplevelArtifactId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

By using a single Jenkins job you can write, as a pre-step, a shell script:

```
mvn clean sca:clean -DskipTests
mvn sca:translate -DskipTests
```

And then define the actual "Goals and options" as:

```
install sca:scan -DskipTests
```

Having them as separate command lines is the only way to have the sca-clean,translate and scan (and report file sending to Fortify) done in one Jenkins job.

Hope this works for you too!

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that they need to be separate commands? I'm executing Maven goals `clean sca:clean sca:translate sca:scan` in my Jenkins job and it works just fine...

Comment: No specific reason, just how it worked for me, when the single line command did not do the work.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac OS Fortify install installs a program called ScanWizard that is able to generate a Maven/Java integrated .sh script to run the scan BUT problem is that it requires you edit the pom and put in the fortify plugin.  On my network, my Nexus server blocks me from downloading it, probably because the artifact is not on Maven central and my Nexus is setup only to be able to mirror from central only.