# HP Fortify SCA integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, fortify

Currently we are using SonarQube as a source code analyser. But now in our organisation they are planning to use HP Fortify SCA for source code analysis. We have integrated SonarQube with Jenkins but i don't know how to integrate HP Fortify with Jenkins. Googled for it but I'm not getting good solution. Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

### [Fortify Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Fortify+Plugin)

Use the Fortify Jenkins Plugin in your continuous integration builds to identify security issues in your source code with Micro Focus Fortify Static Code Analyzer. After the Fortify Static Code Analyzer analysis is complete, you can upload the results to a Micro Focus Fortify Software Security Center server. The Fortify Jenkins Plugin also enables you to view the analysis result details within Jenkins. It provides metrics for each build and an overview of the results, without requiring you to log into Fortify Software Security Center.

With the Fortify Jenkins Plugin, you can integrate Fortify Static Code Analyzer with the following build tools:

- Gradle
- Maven
- MSBuild
- Visual Studio (devenv)

You can also scan your source code directly without a build tool.

[Source](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-jenkins-plugin/1910/Jenkins_Plugin_Help_19.1.0/index.htm#Resources/HTMLelements/Title_Page.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____1).

Answer (score 0):

HPE Fortify does provide a Jenkins Plugin.

There is also a community member who has created a Jenkins plugin that his organization uses to integrate Jenkins and Cloudscan (https://marketplace.saas.hpe.com/fortify/content/fortify-cloudscan-jenkins-plugin).

Here is a good discussion on how one customer is integrating Jenkins and CloudScan in their company (the plugin's author).https://www.protect724.hpe.com/thread/22952

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response ..am not able to access this link https://www.protect724.hpe.com/thread/22952

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use maven for this. There is a plugin available for fortify for maven

[Fortify integration with maven - install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771796/fortify-integration-with-maven-install)

You can use this plugin in your application pom.xml and execute the maven command from jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Integration of HP Fortify with Jenkins :

Step 1) Install Jenkins plugin on cloud server or you can direct access the cloud Jenkins server(if it is already installed on server).

step 2) Create a folder in Jenkins and configure the properties(making changes in **configuration** file on left side).

step 3) once configuration part is done .Post that you have to provide the cloud server link where fortify is installed(scar/ssc) and credentials.

- Test the connection using "Test" button.

  ```
         OR
  ```

  If you have GitHub link, you can directly add the link in Jenkins and used them.

step 4) Now connection is established between Jenkins and fortify-SSC.

Jenkins : It is integration tools ,that provide continuous integration and continuous development(CI /CD).

GitHub:   GitHub is raw code repository , where all the code is saved.

Let me know if you have any question while integrating Jenkins with fortify.Thank you